# What is wrong with my program when i call 'invoke()' function in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

I'd like to add a new row of DataGridview in subthread.i tried like this:

```
delegate void addgridrow(object [] row);
void addInSubthread(object[] row)
{
    if{datagdview.invokerequired)
    {
         addgridrow myadd=new addgridrow(addInSubthread);
         this.invoke(myadd,row);
    }
    else
        datagdview.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

When I called `addInSubthread()`, program throwed `targetparametercountexception` in `this.invoke(....)`.

What is wrong?

Comment: That's clearly *not* your actual code, because the method would be `Invoke` rather than `invoke`. Please copy and paste *real* code, ideally as a short but *complete* example.

Comment: yeah, and `{` instead of `(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
this.invoke(myadd,row);
```

to

```
this.Invoke(myadd,new object[]{row});
```

Comment: Could you tell my why use 'new object[]{row}' instead of 'row'?

Comment: @huaxz1986 Because `Rows.Add` takes an `object[]`. This is the parameter you should give to Invoke which also takes `object[]` as parameter. To pass a single integer to Invoke, for example. you would write `new object[]{123}`. Confusion comes from both method taking `object[]` as parameter.